# Why does glRotate work only once when I don't create an extra class for my openGLWidget?

Tags: python, opengl, pyqt, pyopengl, opengl-compat

I'm writing a GUI for displaying a 6-Axis Motion sensor's output using Python.
The Window is supposed to have an OpenGL Widget displaying the rotation in realtime. Normally I would write a separate class for my `openGLWidget` but since my UI has quite a lot of elements it doesn't seem reasonable to construct it from scratch. Instead I just load the .ui File, find everything I need and that's it. However, the `glRotate()` Function is updated only once and then never again, and I have no clue what might be causing this Problem.

```py
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, uic
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
import OpenGL.GL as gl
import OpenGL.GLU as glu
import sys


class Ui(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Ui, self).__init__()
        uic.loadUi('gl_test.ui', self)

        self.openGLWidget = self.findChild(QtWidgets.QOpenGLWidget, 'openGLWidget')
        self.openGLWidget.initializeGL()
        self.openGLWidget.paintGL = self.paintGL
        self.openGLWidget.initializeGL = self.initializeGL
        self.object = None

        self.rotation = 45.0

#       QTimer for updating the GL Viewport
        self.GLtimer = QTimer()
        self.GLtimer.setInterval(100)
        self.GLtimer.timeout.connect(self.openGLWidget.paintGL)
        self.GLtimer.start()

    def paintGL(self):
        try:
            gl.glClear(gl.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | gl.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT)
            gl.glMatrixMode(gl.GL_PROJECTION)
            gl.glLoadIdentity()
            x, y, width, height = gl.glGetDoublev(gl.GL_VIEWPORT)
            glu.gluPerspective(
                45,  # field of view in degrees
                width / float(height or 1),  # aspect ratio
                .25,  # near clipping plane
                200,  # far clipping plane
            )
            gl.glMatrixMode(gl.GL_MODELVIEW)
            gl.glLoadIdentity()
            gl.glTranslated(0.0, 0.0, -10.0)
            self.rotation += 1
            print(self.rotation)
            gl.glRotate(self.rotation, 1, 0, 0)  # works only once for some reason?
            gl.glCallList(self.object)
        except Exception as exc:
            print(exc)
            pass

    def initializeGL(self):
        try:
            # making an example cube
            self.object = gl.glGenLists(1)
            gl.glNewList(self.object, gl.GL_COMPILE)
            gl.glBegin(gl.GL_QUADS)

            gl.glColor3f(0.0, 1.0, 0.0)
            gl.glVertex3f(1.0, 1.0, -1.0)
            gl.glVertex3f(-1.0, 1.0, -1.0)
            gl.glVertex3f(-1.0, 1.0, 1.0)
            gl.glVertex3f(1.0, 1.0, 1.0)

            gl.glColor3f(0.0, 1.0, 0.0)
            gl.glVertex3f(1.0, -1.0, 1.0)
            gl.glVertex3f(-1.0, -1.0, 1.0)
            gl.glVertex3f(-1.0, -1.0, -1.0)
            gl.glVertex3f(1.0, -1.0, -1.0)

            gl.glColor3f(0.0, 1.0, 0.0)
            gl.glVertex3f(1.0, 1.0, 1.0)
            gl.glVertex3f(-1.0, 1.0, 1.0)
            gl.glVertex3f(-1.0, -1.0, 1.0)
            gl.glVertex3f(1.0, -1.0, 1.0)

            gl.glColor3f(0.0, 1.0, 0.0)
            gl.glVertex3f(1.0, -1.0, -1.0)
            gl.glVertex3f(-1.0, -1.0, -1.0)
            gl.glVertex3f(-1.0, 1.0, -1.0)
            gl.glVertex3f(1.0, 1.0, -1.0)

            gl.glColor3f(0.0, 1.0, 0.0)
            gl.glVertex3f(-1.0, 1.0, 1.0)
            gl.glVertex3f(-1.0, 1.0, -1.0)
            gl.glVertex3f(-1.0, -1.0, -1.0)
            gl.glVertex3f(-1.0, -1.0, 1.0)

            gl.glColor3f(0.0, 1.0, 0.0)
            gl.glVertex3f(1.0, 1.0, -1.0)
            gl.glVertex3f(1.0, 1.0, 1.0)
            gl.glVertex3f(1.0, -1.0, 1.0)
            gl.glVertex3f(1.0, -1.0, -1.0)

            gl.glEnd()
            gl.glEndList()

            gl.glEnable(gl.GL_CULL_FACE)
        except Exception as exc:
            print(exc)
            pass


def main():
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Ui()
    window.show()
    app.exec_()


main()
```

[.ui file code](https://pastebin.com/KMHRCDKD)

This is the part that doesn't work. With self.rotation increasing every time `paintGl()` and therefore `glRotate()` are called I'd expect the Cube to rotate, but for some reason it doesn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is the timer event:

> ```py
> self.GLtimer.timeout.connect(self.openGLWidget.paintGL)
> ```

It is not suggested to call `.paintGL` directly. Note, that OpenGL can't draw anything, the [OpenGL Context](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/OpenGL_Context) has tobe made current before and after drawing, the window has to be updated. You can see the initial drawing, because the first call to `.paintGL` is done by the framework. The following calls, which are sourced by the timer event don't generate a valid output.
You've to call [`.update()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#update), which makes the context current and triggers `.paintGL()` to be called e.g.:

```py
class Ui(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):

        # [...]

        self.GLtimer = QTimer()
        self.GLtimer.setInterval(100)
        self.GLtimer.timeout.connect(self.redraw) 
        self.GLtimer.start()

    def redraw(self):
        # updated the widget - triggers paintGL to be called
        self.openGLWidget.update()
```

[image]

The animation is generated by you original code, except that I've switched to line drawing mode by [`glPolygonMode`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glPolygonMode.xhtml).

```py
gl.glPolygonMode(gl.GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, gl.GL_LINE)
```